# Count by row with variable criteria

Tags: r

I have a data.frame in which I want to perform a count by row versus a specified criterion.  The part I cannot figure out is that I want a different count criterion for each row.

Say I have 10 rows, I want 10 different criteria for the 10 rows.

I tried:  `count.above <- rowSums(Data > rate)`, where rate is a vector with the 10 criterion, but R used only the first as the criterion for the whole frame.

I imagine I could split my frame into 10 vectors and perform this task, but I thought there would be some simple way to do this without resorting to that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this depends whether you want to operate over rows or columns. See below:

This is a job for `mapply` and `Reduce`. Suppose you have a data frame along the lines of

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=2:11,c=3:12)
```

Let's say we want to count the rows where a>6, b>3 and c>5. This is done with `mapply`:

```
mapply(">",df1,c(6,3,5),SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

$a
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

$b
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

$c
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Now we use `Reduce` to find those which are all `TRUE`:

```
Reduce("&",mapply(">",df1,c(6,3,5),SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Lastly, we use `sum` to add them all up:

```
sum(Reduce("&",mapply(">",df1,c(6,3,5),SIMPLIFY=FALSE)))
[1] 4
```

If you want a result for each row rather than a global aggregate, then `apply` is the function to use:

```
apply(df1,1,function(v) sum(v>c(6,3,5)))
[1] 0 0 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

Comment: I think they want one variable to filter over one row and sum, another var to filter next row and sum, etc. Result should be 10 numbers, one for each row.

Comment: Oh okay, in that case it's probably `apply(df1,1,function(v) sum(v>thresholds))` where `thresholds` is the vector of thresholds. I was solving a more difficult problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the dummy data (from @zx8754s solution)

```
# dummy data
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:15, nrow = 3))

myRate <- c(7, 5, 1)
```

**Solution using apply**

Courtesy of @JDL

```
rowSums(apply(df1, 2, function(v) v > myRate))
```

**Alternative solution using the Reduce pattern**

```
Reduce(function(l, v) cbind(l[,1] + (l[,2] > myRate), l[,-2:-1]),
       1:ncol(df1),
       cbind(0, df1))
```

Comment: @JDL i don't have enough rep to comment yet, but do you mean `rowSums(apply(df1,2,function(v) v>thresholds))`?

Comment: No, I don't; the second argument to apply should definitely be `1` because we want one answer for each row. Your version is calculating one answer per column.

Comment: I think we're answering different questions, the OP seems to suggest that each row has a separate constraint. apply(,2,) will apply the "column" of constraints (one for each row), and then rowSums will do the rest.

Comment: Fair enough; the OP isn't the clearest. Hopefully we have given them the info they need!

Comment: I have not tried all of the suggestions, but rowSums(apply(df1, 2, function(v) v > myRate)) is doing precisely what I needed.  Thanks everyone for the assistance.